# Using assert:equals: in pharo

Tags: oop, smalltalk, pharo

I have the following program in Pharo: 2 classes Yacht and  YachtRental, Test Class and YachtRental test. I need to implement the following: on the 4th day, the customer gets discount = 10 % on the daily rate. Here is my code:

I need to implement the following: on the 4th day, the customer gets discount = 10 % on the daily rate. Here is my code:

```
| yachtRental myCruise |
    yachtRental := YachtRental new.
    myCruise := Yacht cruise.
    self assert: (yachtRental priceFor: myCruise days: 4) = 890
```

Basically, I need to be able to implement the discount of 10 % here, however there is a message "Using assert:equals: produces better context on rule failure", could you please help me explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: You probably want to ask the vendor. This message was added to the language by the maintainers for some reason. https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo/issues (But it looks like they want you to use the `:equals` method/operator rather than `=` operator.)

Comment: you need to have a failing method to perceive the difference. I suggest you program the wrong discount and observe the difference of using assert: vs assert:equals: in error report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assert:` takes a boolean, whereas `assert:equals:` takes two expressions. And, `assert:` doesn't know what you are testing, but `assert:equals:` knows that you are testing for two things to be equal.

In case of your test failing, `assert:` cannot print a meaningful failure message since all the information it has access to is `false`, so all it can print is "I expected something to be true but it wasn't."

`assert:equals:` has access to the values of the two expressions and can thus print something like "I expected `foo` to be equal to `bar`".

Since good failure messages are one of the most important aspects of a test library, the authors of the test library are guiding you to use the more expressive assertions in their library instead of a generic "is this true?"

[Note: I am ignoring reflection here. Both methods could, of course, reflectively inspect the source code of the test.]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question is more about the coding of `yachtRental priceFor: myCruise days: 4` than it is about the more subtle issue of `#assert:` versus `#assert:equal:` (which, BTW, Jög explained so clearly.)

Interesting enough, the coding of `#priceFor:days:`, apparently simple, raises some doubts about the test and the discount specification.

Should the discount be applied to every day of the rental period when the period is 4 or more days long? Or should it be applied to days 4, 5, etc.?

In the first case, the logic would be

```
priceFor: aYacht days: anInteger
  | price |
  price := aYacht dailyRate * anInteger.
  anInteger >= 4 ifTrue: [price := price * 0.9].
  ^price
```

and in the second

```
priceFor: aYacht days: anInteger
  | rate |
  rate := aYacht dailyRate.
  ^anInteger < 4
     ifTrue: [rate * anInteger.]
     ifFalse: [rate * 3 + (rate * 0.9 * (anInteger - 3))]
```

Mathematically, the first discount policy would total a price of

```
rate * 4 * 0.9
```

which must equal (pun intended) `890`. This means that `rate` should satisfy

```
rate = 890 / (4 * 0.9) = 247.222222222222
```

which is a rather funny amount, isn't it?

And what about the second policy. In this case we would have

```
rate * 3 + (rate * 0.9 * (4 - 3)) = 890
```

or

```
rate * (3 + 0.9) = 890
```

hence

```
rate = 890 / 3.9 = 228.205128205128
```

which, again, doesn't look as a daily rental rate.

So, my conclusion is that the test must be wrong or the discount policy insufficiently specified.

Answer (score 0):

The system is suggesting that you might want to use

self assert: (yachtRental priceFor: myCruise onDay: 4)
       equals: 890

instead of just the #assert:

but it doesn’t really matter.

What you did is just fine.